# PHP Loop : What am I missing?

Tags: php, foreach

I submitted a different question re this code a few days ago.  I made progress (thanks to y'all) but have run into more roadblocks.

First, the URL:http://rowlandwilliams.com/lepeep

What the code is supposed to do:

1) The code reads the images directory seeking images assigned to the page.  If it finds image pagename0.png (eg, catering0.png), it prints that image to the screen.

2) If it finds multiple images (eg, menu1.png, menu2.png, etc), it prints a slide show. (Note these images start incrementing at 1 not 0.)

3) When it sees no image assigned the page, it moves on.

There are (3) menu page images; (5) about-us images; (1) catering image.

Where the code is not working:

1) On the Menu page, it prints the closing DIV tag first. It then prints the opening and then closing tag again.

2) On the About Us page, it prints the closing DIV first and does not print the opening DIV. This makes NO SENSE to me.

I have troubleshooted this thing for hours and hours and cannot figure out what’s going on.  Help?

```
<div class="page-inner">

<?php

$postname = $post->post_name;
if ($dir = opendir('/home/rowlandwilliams/public_html/lepeep/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/images')) {
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $images[] = $file;
            asort($images); // Cause images to appear in ascending order
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}

$x = 1; // Set variable to be used in counting post img number
$current_iteration=0; // Set variable for case (below)
$last_iteration=count($images)-1; // Set variable for case last iteration for closing DIV tag

foreach($images as $image) {
    $subimg = substr($image, 0, -4);
    if ($subimg == $postname.$x) { // Check if img name (less .png) matches post name
        if ($x == 1) { // If first pass, add opening DIV tag and set cycler to "active"
        echo '<div class="cycler" id="page-cycler">';
        $actstat = 'class="active"';
    } else {
        $actstat = '';
    }
    $x++;
?>

<img <?php echo $actstat; ?> src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Le Peep Houston Breakfast & Lunch Restaurant">

<?php } elseif ($subimg == $postname."0") { ?> // If a single image for page, checks to verify it uses "0" in filename
    <div class="cycler" id="page-cycler">
        <img <?php echo $actstat; ?> src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Le Peep Houston Breakfast & Lunch Restaurant">
<?php } ?>

<?php switch($current_iteration) { ?> // Switch allows for opening and closing statements/HTML
    <?php case 0: ?> // Slot for opening statement, none used however (see semicolon below)

    <?php ; // ?> No statement
    <?php case $last_iteration: ?>
    </div><!-- #page-cycler --> // Closing statement
    <?php break; ?> // End switch
<?php } ?>
<?php $current_iteration++; ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php the_content(); ?> 

</div><!-- #page-inner -->
```

Comment: simplify your code, remove js before you ask. Your code is too difficult to read.

Comment: I agree with @zairwolf. You are making your life 10x more difficult than it needs to be by mixing everything together like that. Instead of doing checks inside your loop for first and last, do the first pass stuff first, then the loop, then the last pass stuff. When you output html, try to keep that section as close to just the html as possible, instead of having it all mixed up with logic.

Answer (score 0):

One part of your problem is that you need a `break` statement after each `case`. Otherwise it will fall through after printing the script code and also print the closing statement in the first iteration.
Changing

```
<?php ; // ?> No statement
```

to

```
<?php break; // ?> No statement
```

will probably remove the unwanted closing tag.

On the "About Us" page you only have one image, however it doesn't end with a 0 in its filename but with a 1 instead. Therefore the if statement which should print the opening `div` will not evaluate to true.
Changing it to

```
elseif ($subimg == $postname."1")
```

probably will work.

Comment: Thank you.  Let me tweak this a bit and see if it works.

Comment: That idd it, IXI.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It would be nice if you could upvote or accept my answer to give me some positive feedback though.